# Identation error after loop

Tags: python, cygwin, sublimetext2

I'm trying to run the following code, but I'm getting an identation error after the for loop. I already tried to fix the identation, but I'm still getting errors. I'm using Sublime Text 2 and compile the code in cygwin.

```
try:
  for x in range(0,3):
    print(j)
    print(i)
    print('row[0] ' + ' ' + str('row[1]') + ' ' + str('row[5])')    
  msg = 'fdfddfd'
  print(msg)
except:
  e = sys.exc_info()[0]
  print str(e)
```

Comment: Could you be more specific (e.g. give the full traceback)? The indentation looks OK as posted, but you have a missing parenthesis on the third `print`.

Comment: You don't close your `print` parenthesis after opening it because you accidentally put it inside quotation marks instead, see  `str('row[5])')`

Comment: ok, thanks. It was the print

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
print('row[0] ' + ' ' + str('row[1]') + ' ' + str('row[5])')
                                                         ^
```

Should be:

```
print('row[0] ' + ' ' + str('row[1]') + ' ' + str('row[5]'))
                                                          ^
```

Numerous commenters have pointed out this issue with it missing the final parentheses (because it was placed inside the string in quotes).

Comment: That will work but it's still unlikely to be right, because it's passing a string literal to `str`, which seems like a colossal waste of time!

Comment: @jonrsharpe also true, but it will fix the indentation error